# Can’t yet set up knitr with TeXShop

Tags: texshop, r, knitr

I want to use knitr with TeXShop.  So far I can’t get knitr and TeXShop to talk.  I’m not sure how to make a reproducible example nor how to make the following succinct, but here’s what I’ve tried:

1. Versions, recently updated, are: R 3.4.2, knitr 1.17, TeXShop 3.88. Within RStudio on a Mac with Sierra OS, knitr has worked well recently and often.  The manuscript I want to migrate is an .rmd.  [Btw, the reason finally to switch is blurred plots as described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29568923/geom-raster-comes-out-smeared-when-saving-to-pdf.  Preview, which recipients are likely to use, no longer has an option to disable Smooth Text and Line Art: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7681819?start=0&tstart=0.  I use TeXShop rather than, for example, LyX, is that my work group does.]
2. Per https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/editors/, I created Knitr.engine.  In TeXShop, knitr now appears as an option in Programs.
3. Per https://iangow.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/using-knitr-with-texshop/, I made Knitr.engine executable with chmod +x ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/Knitr.engine.  Rebooted afterward for good measure.
4. Following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617041/how-can-i-see-the-current-value-of-my-path-variable-on-os-x, included in the returned string for echo $PATH is /Library/TeX/texbin.  Since understanding this part is a bit beyond my skill level, here’s the full response:  /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
5. A year ago TeXShop worked fine for a long document not connected to r.  To check again, I copied https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/005-latex.Rtex to TeXShop then Typeset with Program = LaTeX.  Obviously except the r part, it rendered nicely.  In case this is a clue, in place of r snippets like “…x is \rinline{x[1]}.  And…” the .pdf has a polite “…x is SOMETHING WRONG WITH knitr.  And…”
6. Using the same example file, I changed the TeXShop Program to knitr then tried Typeset.  The console screen is blank and no .pdf is returned.
7. Potentially related questions:  Comments on the unanswered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570145/texshop-and-knitr didn’t get me un-stuck.  I don’t understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901174/synchronise-pdf-to-rnw-in-knitr-with-texshop beyond step 1 enough to know if it should help.  The versioning issue described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915263/knitr-in-texshop-uses-late-r-version doesn’t apply;  The version shown in my R.framework is 3.4.

Thank you very much for any ideas.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: The code of the `.engine` file in the link in 2 still uses `/usr/texbin` to set the path.  Did you change this to `/Library/TeX/texbin`?

Comment: What kind of pre-processing needs to be done? What is the contents of your engine? Do you need to use shell-escape so the proceeding can be done by a package you use?

Comment: I think the problem is with the demo file you are trying (assuming you have (i) installed the `knitr` library in R and (ii) adjusted the path in the `knitr.engine` to be `/Library/TeX/texbin`).  Try running this file instead: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-minimal.Rnw

Comment: @HerbSchulz There is no preprocessing that needs to be done, and documents don't need `shell-escape` for compilation. The `knitr.engine` linked in point 2 works fine once the path is corrected.

Comment: The PATH setting in that engine can actually be removed. TeXShop passes the correct PATH to the execution of the engine. I would call the initial processing line pre-processing.

Comment: First half of comment:  @AlanMunn:  Definite progress with the path update, thank you!  However, when I try to knitr the newer test file you suggest, the fatal error is “You can’t use ‘macro parameter character #’ in horizontal mode.  l.21.”  I see nothing particularly suspect near line 21, nor any reference to horizontal or page orientation.  When I try to knitr with the older demo file in item 5 above...

Comment: [Second half of comment] When I try to knitr with the older demo file in item 5 above, TeXShop now is willing to create a pdf but with the same ‘something wrong with knitr’ replacements for results of r code.  The error message fingers plot(mtcars):  Quitting from lines 43-44… dev.control() called without an open graphics device.  If I remove the plot command, it fails on the next r chunk instead.  Might you have a recommendation to try next??  Meanwhile, thank you!

Comment: The file I linked to compiles properly for me (TL 2017, R 3.3), but the other file also produces the something wrong output.  The error you're getting seems to be on the `#` comment marker in the embedded R code. And you're using the `knitr` engine to compile?

Comment: I've discovered the problem: there is a difference between `.Rnw` and `.Rtex` source file syntax.  The other document uses the `.Rtex` syntax for the embedded R code and the file I linked to uses the `.Rnw` syntax.   See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/vignettes/knitr-refcard.pdf for a summary. If I change the file extension of the file you link to to `.Rtex` it compiles properly for me. (Unfortunately TeXShop doesn't know about that extension, though.)

Comment: @AlanMunn  Thank you SO much.  I'll try to remember in the future to look at the vignettes when I'm stuck.  Meanwhile this lets me get back to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some things that should help.

1. The `knitr.engine` you linked to sets an old path for the TeX binaries.  It should be `/Library/TeX/texbin` But as Herb Shulz notes in the comments, the path doesn't actually matter, since TeXShop sets the path correctly.
2. Make sure you have installed the `knitr` package in R.
3. `knitr` recognizes various kinds of syntax for embedding the R code, and this depends on the file extension of the source file. The [code you linked to](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/005-latex.Rtex) is an `.Rtex` file, and not an `.Rnw` file, which uses a different embedding syntax.

The `.Rtex` syntax is

```
% begin.rcode 

% end.rcode
```

But this requires that you save the file as `.Rtex`, which TeXShop unfortunately does not allow you to do. (Even though it can open such files.)

The `.Rnw` syntax is

```
<< ... >>=

@
```

There are some other differences. See [`knitr` Reference Card](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/vignettes/knitr-refcard.pdf) for a quick overview.

Finally, there is also `.Rmd` syntax:

````
```{r ... }

```
````

But TeXShop also doesn't know how to save this extension either (although it can open such files.)

Because of the way TeXShop manages its Save dialogue, only a specified set of file extensions are allowed, so the full range of files that `knitr` recognizes are not available if you are trying to save a new untitled document. At present, TeXShop only knows about `.Rnw` files. However, TeXShop can read other file types without any trouble, so you can manually change the file extension to `.Rtex` and then in the Finder choose to have that file type be always opened by TeXShop (choose Get Info for the selected file and then choose TeXShop as the application to open the file.)

Furthermore, if you add

```
% !TEX TS-program = knitr
```

to the first line of your document, the `knitr` engine will automatically be chosen for that file.